# dynamic select input in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use unique function to create the selectInput choices. However, my data looks like this below, which would require multiple mappings. For example,something like:

```
choices = c(`Pro Forma` = c('Pro-forma', 'ProForma', 'Proforma', 'Pro-Forma')`)
```

but not sure what's the correct syntax.

```
> unique(heatmap_raw$Status)
# [1] "Active"     "Redeeming"  "Proforma"   NA           "Pro-forma"  "ProForma" 
# [7] "na"         "40act"      "40 Act"     "Pro-Forma"  "40ACT"      "UCITS"   

selectInput("select month", label = ("Select Month"),
choices = c(unique(month(heatmap_raw$period))))
```

Comment: Is your question really about shiny, or text manipulation (how to make the different punctuations resolve to the same thing)?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Thanks for looking into it. I think the question is about both as I'm not sure what's the correct syntax in Shiny to pass multiple punctuations. `choices = c(`Pro Forma` = c('Pro-forma', 'ProForma', 'Proforma', 'Pro-Forma')`)` This way doesn't work as it still creates 4 different options in the dropdown menu but I just need one and all the four types of data will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your dataset is not normalized.  If you have a bunch of non-standard status codes like:

```
status <- c( "Active","Redeeming","Proforma",NA,"Pro-forma","ProForma","na",
             "40act","40 Act","Pro-Forma","40ACT","UCITS")
```

I would standardize them for case and punctuation:

```
status <- tolower(gsub("\\W","",status))
# plus, do something for the NA vs. "na" status
status[is.na(status)] <- "na" # or something else, just to achieve consistency
```

Starting with clean data will avoid the need for workarounds later.